# From integral to expected value of probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

I was reading about [KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) and stumbled upon this [post](http://bjlkeng.github.io/posts/semi-supervised-learning-with-variational-autoencoders/). In the Equation (2), we can see the following:

\begin{align*}
D_{KL}(Q||P) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} q(\theta|X) \log\frac{q(\theta|X)}{p(\theta|X)} d\theta \\
             &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} q(\theta|X) \log\frac{q(\theta|X)}{p(\theta,X)} d\theta +
                \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} q(\theta|X) \log{p(X)} d\theta \\
             &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} q(\theta|X) \log\frac{q(\theta|X)}{p(\theta,X)} d\theta +
                \log{p(X)} \\
             &= E_q\left[\log\frac{q(\theta|X)}{p(\theta,X)}\right] + \log p(X) \\
            \tag{2}
\end{align*}

To go from line (1) to line (2), $p(\theta|X) = \frac{p(\theta,X)}{p(X)}$ and $\log{AB} = \log{A} + \log{B}$ are applied. Then, to go from line (2) to (3): given that $q(\theta|X)$ is a probability, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} q(\theta|X) = 1$ is applied. I don't understand how to go from line (3) to line (4). I think the same rule cannot be applied because the other terms are also dependent of $\theta$. Can someone help me to understand why:

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} q(\theta|X) \log\frac{q(\theta|X)}{p(\theta,X)} d\theta = E_q\left[\log\frac{q(\theta|X)}{p(\theta,X)}\right]
\end{align*}

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a small typo on the RHS but note that for every function $g$, $$E_{q(\ \mid x)}(g(\theta))=\int_\mathbb Rg(\theta)q(\theta\mid x)d\theta$$ and use this for $$g(\theta)=\log\frac{q(\theta\mid x)}{p(\theta,x)}$$

Comment: Oh, I think I see now. $q(\ \mid x)$ is the density used for "averaging" the $g(\theta)$. I assume the typo is that $E_{q}$ must have the $(\ \mid x)$, correct? Thanks.